# MySQL query - want to show unique entries only

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
create table events 
(
    sensor_id integer not null,
    event_type integer not null,
    value integer not null,
    time timestamp unique not null
);
```

What I want is to show unique entries and take the entries which has maximum time, I have written this query

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM events AS B 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT sensor_id, event_type, MAX(time) AS MaxDateTime 
            FROM events
            GROUP BY sensor_id, event_type
            ORDER BY MAxDateTime DESC) A ON B.time = A.MaxDateTime
```

What I want is to skip the time column and just show sensor_id, event_type and value in the final result, any thoughts?

Comment: change `b.*` to `B.sensor_ID, B.event_Type, B.Value`

Comment: but then what about B.time = A.MaxDateTime?

Comment: that's the join critiera.  I would think you would want to join on that and sensor_Id and event_Type...  the time will not be displayed, only what's in the select will be.

Comment: okay let me try a moment.

Comment: _but then what about B.time = A.MaxDateTime?_ Nothing. Projection and selection are different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- change B.* to the desired columns in your output...
- ordering the subquery didn't' make sense so I moved it to the outer  (note you can still order by a column that's not displayed!)
- I added join criteria to include sensor and event_Type

.

```
SELECT  B.sensor_ID, B.event_Type, B.Value
FROM events AS B 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT distinct sensor_id, event_type, max(time) AS MaxDateTime 
            FROM events
            GROUP BY sensor_id, event_type) A 
  on B.time = A.MaxDateTime
 and B.Sensor_ID = A.Sensor_ID
 and B.Event_Type = A.Event_Type
ORDER BY B.Time
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row per `sensor_id` with the maximum time, then something like this:

```
select e.*
from events e
where e.time = (select max(e2.time)
                from events e2
                where e2.sensor_id = e.sensor_id
               );
```

EDIT:

If you want the max per sensor and event, then include that in the correlation clause:

```
select e.*
from events e
where e.time = (select max(e2.time)
                from events e2
                where e2.sensor_id = e.sensor_id and
                      e2.event_type = e.event_type
               );
```

Comment: I think you'd need additional coorlation on the subquyer:  `e2.event_Type = E.Event_Type`.  it seems they want max per sensor and event.